# Finding the hidden Red Arrow thug in Deus Ex

Tags: deus-ex

[Deus Ex Wiki says about the Wan Chai Market level:](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Wan_Chai_Market)

> If the player noclips into the scenery above the police station, they may find a Red Arrow thug stuck in a T-Pose. If removed from the T-Pose, he will speak to the player in dialogue cut from the final game.

I could find a closed and unused room above the police station, but that room is totally empty. It has only some pillars with their shadow, but nothing that I can use. How can I make the mentioned guy appear?

(map patch didn't help on it)

EDIT: I'm not talking about "Max Chen on the roof", it must be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unused conversation with a Red Arrow thug that was relevant in early versions of the story line, but didn't make any sense in the current one.  Evidently, rather than delete the content, the character was moved off to the side.  See this, if you want to see what it was talking about and a bit of a hint (if you can catch it) where he is:

Comment: Wow, I haven't ever thought that the game contains cut conversations like this! Thank you very much for showing! =)